# NULL sorting in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to specify the following in the `order by` statement in BigQuery, or do the equivalent?

```
SELECT * FROM books
ORDER BY books ASC (nulls first)
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM books
ORDER BY books ASC (nulls last)
```

This would need to be within the item itself, not adding on a second item such as:

```
ORDER BY books IS NULL ASC, books ASC
```

Ideally, I'd like to apply it across an entire table (all queries for it) or something like that.

Here is this feature in Postgres: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/651174

Comment: as looks like you are rejecting in advance possible workarounds - looks like this is less of a question but rather a feature request and thus should go to respective tracker?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant right, I was seeing if this item is currently available in BQ or it's a feature not yet supported?

Comment: does'n look like supported in BigQuery

Comment: but by default nulls are ordered as first for ASC and last for DESC. so if you need to revert this - how about something silly like (just as an simplified example)  `order by IFNULL(book, 'zzzzzzzz')` for `nulls last` option for ASC and `nulls first` for DESC - just asking. Of course 'zzzzzz' should be domain specific

Comment: [Here is the feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905901) for specifying the ordering of NULLs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since May 1st 2020, NULLS FIRST and NULLS LAST feature is available

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#order_by_clause

Your example can be expressed as

```sql
SELECT * FROM books
ORDER BY books ASC NULLS FIRST
```

and

```sql
SELECT * FROM books
ORDER BY books ASC NULLS LAST
```

Comment: i think  you meant `ORDER BY books ASC NULLS LAST` as FIRST in this case is by default. right?

Comment: You are right about the default value. I added a NULLS LAST example to have 1 to 1 mapping with examples in the question.

Comment: Thank you for broadcasting JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY function :)